# Padding-bottom not works for fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, css-position, mousewheel

I would like to use a fixed parent div for a scrollable child.

My theory is to use a `div` with `position:fixed;` and `overflow:hidden;`. The `height` will be `100%`. The child `div` will be scrollable.

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:50px;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1000000;
    top:0;
}

.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.content {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

The HTML is very simple..

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used jquery mousewheel for scrolling. The working example is available at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGLWLO

The problem is that I can't scroll to the bottom. I added `50px padding` for the fixed div, and margin for the child div.. but no luck. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.fixed`

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:50px;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1000000;
    top:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.content {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvEzXP

Notice that you also should increase the width if you do so.

More information about [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the answer. One more thing, do you have idea what happens with the bottom padding when I change the top value? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdrvvO

Comment: You have a height of 100% and shift it down. You could use (in the new browsers) `height: calc(100% - 150px);` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVzdqx